# Custom Unmarshal Tags in Golang from Custom Mapping

Tags: go

I'm trying to unmap a struct based on a custom mapping in my DB that specifies which json tags correspond to which struct fields.

I have a basic working solution that looks somewhat like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Mapping struct {
    ObjColumnName  string
    JSONColumnName string
}

type Obj struct {
    Name string
    Age  float64
    m    []Mapping
}

func (o *Obj) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var a map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(data, &a)

    for _, mapping := range o.m {
        switch mapping.ObjColumnName {
        case "Name":
            o.Name = a[mapping.JSONColumnName].(string)
        case "Age":
            o.Age = a[mapping.JSONColumnName].(float64)
        default:
            return errors.New("Unknown mapping")
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    o := Obj{
        m: []Mapping{
            {
                ObjColumnName:  "Name",
                JSONColumnName: "first_name_last_name",
            },
            {
                ObjColumnName:  "Age",
                JSONColumnName: "years_since_birth",
            },
        },
    }
    blob := `{"first_name_last_name": "Jason Bourne", "years_since_birth": 15}`
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(blob), &o); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Custom Unmapped: %+v", o)
    // Custom Unmapped: {Name:Jason Bourne Age:15 m:[{ObjColumnName:Name JSONColumnName:first_name_last_name} {ObjColumnName:Age JSONColumnName:years_since_birth}]}

}
```

so you can see here that we can successfully change what maps to `Name` and what maps to `Age`.

However what I don't like about this implementation is:

1. I have to basically redefine the object types here:

```
        case "Name":
            o.Name = a[mapping.JSONColumnName].(string)
        case "Age":
            o.Age = a[mapping.JSONColumnName].(float64)
```

2. I think attaching the mappings to `Obj` (`Obj.m`) is a little hacky

Is there a better way to dynamically set the json tags when Unmarshalling so that I don't have to do hacky stuff like this?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, was pigeon-holed into thinking I have to do some fancy reflection. You can just remap the keys and then not do any fancy unmarshalling: https://go.dev/play/p/kSJbSAcVLm6

This isn't ideal from a performance perspective though. If someone could answer how to do it without doing 2 Unmarshall's that would be great!